# Why can we write $\cos{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...=1+o(x)$?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, asymptotics

We can write $\cos{x}$ as

$$\cos{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...\tag{1}$$

For any $i=1,2,3,...$ and $|x|<1$ we have that

$$\frac{x^{2i}}{x}=x^{2i-1}\leq x$$

which we can make as small we we desire by choosing a sufficiently tight interval around zero.

Thus, for $i=1,2,3,...$

$$x^{2i}=o(x)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to 0)$$

Thus, each right-hand side term in $(1)$ is $o(x)$. **But what allows us to say that all of them together are $o(x)$?** The difficulty for me is the fact that there are infinite terms. I haven't studied such series yet.

Answer (score 4):

$|-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...|\leq {x^{2}}  [\frac 1 {2!}+\frac 1 {4!}+...]$ for $|x| <1$. Also, $|\frac 1 {2!}+\frac 1 {4!}+...| <e$. Hence, $|\cos x -1|\leq ex^{2}=o(x)$.